# Different Datasets for Training and testing a machine learning model

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am currently working on the BNP Paribas Cardiff Claim Management dataset from kaggle & I have finished writing my code on python (jupyter notebook) for the train dataset where I have used 20% of it to test. This study requires me to test my model on a completely different dataset test.csv and append the predicted probabilities on the sample_sumbission.csv. How do I go about it. What changes would I have to make since I have made many tweaks to the training dataset using feature selection techniques

Comment: You should make the same "tweaks" to the test dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define the following:

```
Xtrain - Training data with shape nxm where n is number of records and m is features
ytrain - Target for each row in Xtrain
model - The chosen model
ypred_train - model(Xtrain)
```

I assume you have had a dataset `data` of which you have done some cleaning/feature-engineering such that `Xtrain = clean(data)`.

Since your model is trained over `Xtrain` which has been "transformed" using `clean`, you'll need to make sure that `Xtest = clean(data_test)`

You can do it in different ways, where the simplest is

1. Define a function `clean` e.g

```py
def clean(X):
   """ Cleans the data in X
    
    input
    ------

     X: pandas.DataFrame
   """
   X["sum"] = X["feature1"] + X["feature2"]
   X["lower"] = X["string_feature"].str.lower()
   X.drop(columns=["string"], inplace=True)
   return X #Cleaned data
```

and then you can simply do

```py
Xtrain = clean(data)
Xtest = clean(data_test)
ytest = model(Xtest)
```

2. Depending on what you are doing in `clean` you can look at [pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)

Comment: How do I get ytest considering that my test dataset doesn't have a target column